# Intersection of a polar hyper plane and a quadric is a conic

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Let $\mathbb{R} P^3$ be the real projective space of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and Q be a quadric defined as
$$ 
Q = \left\{\,\left[\,\left(\begin{smallmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,\right] \in \mathbb{R}P^3 \mid x_1^2 + x_2^2 -x_3^2 -x_4^2 = 0 \,\right\}
$$
The associated symetric bilinear form of the the quadratic form mentioned in the quadric above is non-degenerate. By using the polarisations theorem I arrive at the result
$$B(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 - x_3y_3 - x_4y_4 \qquad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^4$$
The polar hyperplane $E \subset \mathbb{R} P^3$ of a point $[\, p\,] \in \mathbb{R} P^3$ is defined as
$$ E = \{\,\left[\, x \,\right] \in \mathbb{R}P^3 \mid B(p,x) = 0 \,\} $$
Show that

- $\mathcal{C} = Q \cap E \neq \emptyset$
- $\mathcal{C}$ is a non-degenerate conic (conic section: circle, ellipse, parabola, hyperbola)

I have tried a couple of things - here is a GeoGebra plot of mine 
[I'm not allowed to post a picture (<>_<>)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9YpU.png)

With an image, it is somehow clear that the intersection is surely not empty. Here are the problems

1. The quadric (even from the projective point of view) is a manifold of codimension 2 and the plane is a 2-dimensional subspace but this is a not enough to conclude the first question.
2. I have tried to construct a point that lies in the intersection. I could not find anything
3. To prove that the intersection is a conic, I can equivalently show that $|C| \geq 5$. Since $\mathcal{C}$ is not empty, there is at least one point $[\, r\,] \in \mathcal{C}$ so do $-r$. I failed to find another 3 points.
4. My idea of how to show, that the conic is non-degenerate is to show, that it does not contain a line. This can be achieved by showing, that no 3 points in $\mathcal{C}$ lie on the same line.

Since I failed at showing 1, 3, I am just out of ideas. Here is the honor mention
For any $[\,x\,] \in \mathcal{C}$ - the line through $[\,p\,],  [\,x\,]$ is a tangent of the quadric $Q$ at $[\, x \,]$ and only $[\, x\,]$. What worries me the most is, that none of these ideas involves the bilinear form (except for the last one). What am I missing?

Comment: Are you allowed to use matrix methods? E.g., $Q$ has matrix equation $\mathbf X^TA\mathbf X=0$ with $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1,-1)$ and you can parameterize $E$ as $\mathbf X = M\mathbf x$ via a $4\times3$ matrix $M$ (effectively, impose a coordinate system on $E$). The intersection is then given by the equation $(M\mathbf x)^TA(M\mathbf x)=\mathbf x^T(M^TAM)\mathbf x=0$, which is the equation of a quadric on $E$. You can then reason about $M^TAM$ to determine degeneracy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, I can use the matrix method. It is just the diagonalization of the bilinear form,  where $X$ is the orthogonal transformation made of eigenvectors but what is this $M$, that I can use to parameterize $E$ in such a way. To begin with $E$ lies in the projective space and $X$ is a real matrix and $x$ is a projective point  - isn't it ? In which kind of way does this $M$ related to the bilinear form ?

Comment: Choose any three linearly-independent points $\mathbf M_j$ on $E$. Every point on $E$ can then be written as a linear combination $\sum_j x_jM_j$, $M\mathbf x$ in matrix form. (This lifts $\mathbf x\in\mathbb{RP}^2$ to $\mathbb{RP}^3$.) It’s easy to work out that $(M^TAM)_{ij}=B(M_i,M_j)$.

Comment: BTW, $Q\cap E\ne\emptyset$ doesn’t hold for all nondegenerate quadrics, so you’ll need to use the specific properties of this one to prove it (it’s a hyperboloid of one sheet).

Comment: It's kinda clear that $Q \cap E$ does not hold for just any quadric - one of the easier cases to imagine is that of the ellipsoid.  Thank you, I'll try to work it out.

Comment: Can you please suggest some references for polar hyperplane

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @amd ! $B$ can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
    B\left(\left[\begin{matrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        x_4  \\
    \end{matrix}\right],
    \left[\begin{matrix}
        y_1 \\
        y_2 \\
        y_3 \\
        y_4   \\
    \end{matrix}\right]\right) &= 
    \left[\begin{matrix}
        y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
    \left[\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & -1& 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
    \end{matrix}\right]
    \left[\begin{matrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        x_4  \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
    = y^T A x
\end{align*}
Let $[\,p\,] \in \mathbb{R} P^3$ and denote the set
    $$E = \{\, [\,x\,] \in \mathbb{R} P^3 \mid B(x,p) =  0 \,\} $$
    as the polar hyper plane w.r.t $P$. Let $[\,v^{(1)}\,], [\,v^{(2)}\,], [\,v^{(3)}\,] \in E$  be any arbitrary linear independent points. For some $r_1, r_2, r_3 \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{\,0\,\}$ the representative $x$ of any point $[\,x\,] \in E$ can be characterized as
    $$ x =  r_1 v^{(1)} + r_2 v^{(2)} + r_3v^{(3)} = \left[\begin{matrix} v^{(1)} &  v^{(2)} & v^{(3)} \end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}  r_1 \\  r_2  \\ r_3\end{matrix}\right] = Mr $$
    Where $M$ denote the matrix on the left and $r$ the  vector on the right.
    We can write
    $$x^T A \,x = (Mr)^T A\, (Mr) = r^T (M^T A \,M) \,r$$
    where
    \begin{align*}
    B^\ast = M^T A \,M = 
    \left[\begin{matrix}
    B(v^{(1)}, v^{(1)}) &  B(v^{(1)}, v^{(2)}) &  B(v^{(1)}, v^{(3)})   \\
    B(v^{(2)}, v^{(1)}) &  B(v^{(2)}, v^{(2)}) &  B(v^{(2)}, v^{(3)})   \\
    B(v^{(3)}, v^{(1)}) &  B(v^{(3)}, v^{(2)}) &  B(v^{(3)}, v^{(3)})   \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
\end{align*}
    Since $B$ is non-degenerate and $v^{(1,2,3)}$ build a linear independent system, the matrix $B^\ast$ is symmetric with
    $$\textrm{det}(B^\ast) = \textrm{det}(M^T) \textrm{det}(A) \textrm{det}(M)   \neq 0$$
    representing a non-degenerate bilinear form in $\mathbb{R}^3$. $r$ can be seen as a representative of a point $[\,r\,] \in \mathbb{R} P^2$, therefore the set
    $$\mathcal{C} = \{\,[\,r\,] \in  \mathbb{R} P^2 \mid r^T B^\ast r = 0 \,\}$$
    defines a non-degenerate quadric in $\mathbb{R} P^2$ - a conic, especially $\mathcal{C} \neq \emptyset $